# retrieve firebase data as json

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve data stored in firebase database but in proper Json format, the problem is when using `String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue())` it is not the correct json format.
For example, if the the data

```
{
  "properties" : {
     "last_update" : "15-02-2017 02:48:00 pm",
     "last_update_code" : "1258884"  
  } 
}
```

the returned value becomes like that

```
properties = {last_update = 15-02-2017 02:48:00 pm,last_update_code = 1258884}
```

without the quotes or (:) .

so it there a way to get the data as string in the first format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously the pojo class is the most neat and the easiest way to achieve my goal

### first

created the classes that represents my json file:

for that json file:

> {   "data" : {
>       "text" : {
>         "loading" : {
>           "intro_text" : "hi"
>             }
>         }    } }

create these classes:

pojo, data, text, loading such like that:

```
public class Pojo{
    private Data data;

    public void setData(Data data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Data getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

public class Data {
    private Text text;

    public void setText(Text text){
        this.text = text;
    }
    public Text getText(){
        return this.text;
    }
}

public class Text {
    private Loading loading;

    public void setLoading(Loading loading){
        this.loading = loading;
    }
    public Loading getLoading(){
        return this.loading;
    }
}

public class Loading {
    private String intro_text;

    public void setIntro_text(String intro_text){
        this.intro_text = intro_text;
    }
    public String getIntro_text(){
        return this.intro_text;
}
```

}

### Second

apply this method on this part of file
assuming that (data) is the first sub node in the json file, so the is ref = "" (no ref as it is the first node)

```
 Database database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("");
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Pojo pojo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pojo.class);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String reqJson= gson.toJson(pojo);
        return reqJson
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I do. **First, create a java object from DataSnapshot then get JSON from that object using Gson.**

```
Object object = datasnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
```

Comment: Perfect. No need to create a unnecessary Pojo class to get response in json. 

Kotlin version of this answer
val `object` = dataSnapshot.getValue(Any::class.java)
                val json = Gson().toJson(`object`)

Answer (score 5):

You'll get the returned value that you're getting when you try to convert a `json` to `String`.

So, instead of doing that, you can use one of the following methods :-

First :-

```
String lastUpdate = dataSnapshot.child(last_update).getValue(String.class);
String last_update_code = dataSnapshot.child(last_update_code).getValue(String.class);
```

Second :-

Define a POJO that maps to your Json. After that, use the following code.

```
YourPOJO yourPOJO = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourPOJO.class);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: considering the first solution, I think it wont work if it was nested nodes, 
about the pojo class I am trying it now and will tell you, thank!

Comment: If there's a nested node, then you can just call `dataSnapshot.child(first_child_node).child(second_child_node).getValue()`

Comment: However, using a POJO class is usually the best way to go!

Comment: I tried the pojo class, It worked and it is easy too, thanks!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use `Gson` to convert result to json string e.g.

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

Comment: I tried it, but I think it does not work on nested nodes

Comment: Kind of messy but you could also do `PojoClass myPojo = dataSnapshot.getValue(PojoClass.class)` with `PojoClass` being java class that maps to your json.....and then use `gson` to convert that.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible method can be to use the URL based data read. If you you know the root which contains json file. Simply add .json to the end of the reference url of the node and it can be read as json file using the http. Consider the following as example.
https://database-name.firebaseio.com/profiles/key.json
The permission can be public or authorized and can be checked before making request.